# Internship expected compensation

Tags: salary, internship, applications

How should I answer the question about expected compensation on a internship position application? I haven't had any internship experiences before.

Answer (score 3):

Do some research online, and try to find what is the average compensation for an internship in your field.

Try also to talk with other fellow students who have recently been in an internship to learn from their experience.

Finally, does the internship description offer any hint about the payment for the internship?

According to the place where you are, payed internship are the norm or they might even get offended by an intern asking for being payed.